# Accessing Session in Domain Object

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

We use event sourcing in our app and also have a strict need to track the user who initiated changes to many of our objects. Currently we have code like this

```
class Order { 
  setNameBy(newname, User user) {
    applyChange(new OrderRenamed(user.id, newname));
  }
  :
}
```

Since most of our methods are like this and all of them are called like this

```
setNameBy("a new name", SessionContext.currentUser)
```

we where contemplating accessing the SessionContext inside the domain object. i.e:

```
setNameBy(newname, User user) {
  applyChange(new OrderRenamed(user.id, newname));
}
```

becomes

```
setName(newname) {
  applyChange(new OrderRenamed(SessionContext.currenUser.id, newname));
}
```

I personally prefer the later method signature as it seams more natural on the other hand it feels a bit messy to access the SessionContext inside the Domain object.

So how do you best handle Session data like this in DDD/CQRS apps ?. Is it OK to access the SessionContext in the Domain objects or should I use other methods like event enrichment to add this information to the events emitted from the domain ?.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If tracking the user who initiated the change occurs frequently, then the SessionContext becomes an inherent part of the solution and therefore IMO the path of least resistance (a good enough solution). Perhaps a rewording to UserContext will make it sound less like a "dirty" technical coupling? :)

I often use a Thread bound Context in my applications (both Event sourced and not), and if your SessionContext.currentUser throws an exception in case a SessionContext hasn't been bound to the thread, then it can also help spot bugs during testing (at least it has for me).

The alternative could be to mark the Event as requiring User tracking (e.g. using an interface) and then enrich the event afterwards. This just feels a bit more cumbersome to me and can perhaps make problem solving harder since an unbound SessionContext exception will occur outside the business function requiring the User information.

Both solutions are IMO good enough solutions, so it's mostly a matter of where you want the coupling to the SessionContext.

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to keep my domain models completely ignorant of outside details. If your domain objects require the user id to enforce business rules I would use your current approach and send the User as an argument. If you only need the user id for tracking/auditing purposes you can enrich the event.